# How do I seamlessly share iMessage from Mac OS X El Capitan to my Windows 10 PC?

Tags: iphone, windows, messages, remote-control

I'm generally a Windows 10 user, but my family is all using iPhones, because of that I would like to be able to access my iMessage messages from my Windows 10 computer (and Android phone if possible), but the only way I've come up with is using some sort of a seamless window sharing from Mac to Windows. Is this the best method for sharing or is there a better way? If it is, what programs do you know of that makes this possible? I've been looking around a bit, but haven't found anything that isn't enterprise software.

**Thank you!**

Comment: There is no program available for windows to get your iMessages. iMessage was created as an exclusive and free way to message other Apple device users. The messages are also sent and delivered through apple, and the APIs are private. You cannot even view iMessages for your account on the iCloud.com account interface.My recommendation is to turn off iMessage and force SMS messages be sent to you and be sent by you, and then share your SMS messages somehow. But this will block anyone using an iMessage only device (iPad, iPod, etc).

Comment: @Jahhein I'm aware of this. That is why I'm looking for a program to access them via a Mac.